# variable sync on multithread environments

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

The questions are limited to X86/LINUX environment.

**One thread write a var with a lock,other threads read this var without lock.
  When the write thread unlocked,Could other threads read the new value immediately?**

```
 volatile int a=0;

   /* thread 1(write) */    
   lock();  
   a = 10;  
   unlock();  

   /* thread 2(read) */  
   printf("%d",a);
```

**One thread read a var with a lock,another thread write this var without lock.
   When the read thread read after write complete,Could it read the new value     immediately?**

```
   volatile int a=0;

   /* thread 1(read) */  
   lock();  
   printf("%d",a);  
   unlock();  

   /* thread 2(write) */  
   a = 10;
```

Comment: As Als said，we can ensure the value is updated to memory after unlock.So that's enough for me.Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

> One thread write a var with a lock,other threads read this var without lock. When the write thread unlocked,Could other threads read the new value immediately?

Yes, they can, but what ensures all the reading threads will not read before the writing starts?

> One thread read a var with a lock,another thread write this var without lock. When the read thread read after write complete,Could it read the new value immediately?

Yes, but again what ensures the ordering of the read and writes?

Since you need the operations to occur in a certain scenario you will need to provide some form of **synchronization** here. Simplest is to use an an signalling counter like **Semaphore**.
Note that `volatile` does not provide you with ordering of the sequences it only ensures no optimization on compilres part, So the ordering is still your responsibility.

Comment: So is this due to the memory barrier?
I have seen that spin_lock in linux kernel has a memory barrier,but the pthread implementation does not have.I wonder how does pthread_spin_lock can sync the vars?

Comment: @marble: Indeed, You need a memory barrier for acheiving the ordering,I am not sure what `pthread_spin_lock` uses but my guess is it should be using a memory barrier.

Comment: @marble:  I guess it depends on the implementation of the `unlock()` function.  If there's nothing in it to force the variable to be flushed to main memory, threads running on other processors might indeed see it as out of date.

Answer (score 2):

They could, but it's not guaranteed.  In both cases, you've got
undefined behavior.  As soon as more than one thread accesses an object,
and at least one thread modifies it, **all** accesses must be
synchronized, or undefined behavior results.

This is true according the C++11 and Posix.  Linux follows the Posix
rules.  In some versions of VC++, `volatile` has been extended with
atomic semantics.  (Under Posix, the only semantics associated with
`volatile` concern signals and `longjmp`/`setjmp`.  It's totally
irrelevant and largely ignored in threading.)

Comment: Could you give a link which describe this issue in C++ or POSIX specifications?I think when unlock() completes,the new value is ensured to be written to memory.so other threads can read the new value.

Comment: @marble §4.10 of the Posix standard: "Applications shall ensure that
access to any memory location by more than one thread of control
(threads or processes) is restricted such that no thread of control can 
read or modify a memory location while another thread of control may be
modifying it."  The effects of §1.10 of C++11 result in the same rule.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. Just because a variable is enclosed within a lock, it doesn't mean to say that other threads can't read it *even in the lock* if other parts of your code don't protect access to `a`. In your first example, you lock access to the code which changes `a` but then after the `unlock()` you use an unprotected read. Just before or during that read, another thread could change the value of `a` leaving you with quite unexpected and unpredictable results.

In other words, you are not locking access to a variable per se, but restricting certain paths in the code to be *mutually exclusive*

Additionally, your use of `volatile` is concerning. I'm not sure why you used it but I'm guessing it will not give you what you were expecting. Please read [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: The issue comes from a non blocking LRU i'm implementing.I'm sure the variable is modified only by one thread at the meanwhile. So if the read thread could get the new value after unlock,it's enough for me.

Comment: @marble: Nothing is blocking the read so it's possible that a write could be taking place part way through the read, unless you're sure that both your read and write are atomic - `volatile` will not give you that. If you absolutely want to avoid such issues then locking read as well as write operations is prudent.